# List element gets deselected when list is sorted

Tags: macos, swiftui

Note: Edited so that sample code ought to compile & run on MacOS 14.2.1, Xcode 15.2

I have a list in the sidebar of a NavigationSplit view. If I sort the underlying data, any selection disappears:

```
import SwiftUI

typealias Key = UUID

protocol Model: AnyObject, Identifiable, Hashable, Equatable {
    typealias Key = UUID
    var id: Key { get set }
    var title: String { get set }
}
extension Model {
    static func == (lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool { lhs.id == rhs.id }
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(id)
    }
}
struct ModelIndex: Identifiable {
    typealias Key = UUID
    var id: Key
    var title: String
    
    init(_ model: any Model) {
        id = model.id
        title = model.title
    }
}
@main
struct ListSelectApp: App {
    @State private var story = Story()
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environment(story)
        }
    }
}
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(Story.self) private var story
    @State private var columnVisibilty: NavigationSplitViewVisibility = .all
    @State private var selection: Key?
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView(columnVisibility: $columnVisibilty) {
            VStack {
                List(story.sortedCast, selection: $selection) { member in
                    NavigationLink(value: member) {
                        Text(member.title)
                    }
                    .navigationDestination(for: CastMember.self) { member in
                        DetailView(selection: $selection)
                    }
                }
            }
            .modifier(SortMenu())
            
        } detail: {
            Text("Please Select Cast Member")
        }
        .navigationTitle(story.title(selection: selection))
    }
}

extension ContentView {
    private struct SortMenu: ViewModifier {
        @Environment(Story.self) private var story
        
        func body(content: Content) -> some View {
            content
                .toolbar() {
                    ToolbarItem {
                        Menu {
                            Button {
                                story.sortedCast = story.sortCast(on: .last, upDown: .up)
                            } label: { MenuLabel(label: "Last name", systemName: "arrow.up") }
                            Button {
                                story.sortedCast = story.sortCast(on: .last, upDown: .down)
                            } label: { MenuLabel(label: "Last name", systemName: "arrow.down") }
                        } label: { Image(systemName: "arrow.up.arrow.down") }
                            .help("Sort List")
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}

struct MenuLabel: View {
    var label: String
    var systemName: String
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text(label)
            Image(systemName: systemName)
        }
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {
    @Environment(Story.self) private var story
    @Binding var selection: Key?
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            if let s = selection, let item = story.cast[s] {
                Text(item.title)
            } else { Text("Please Select Cast Member") }
        }
    }
}
struct CastData {
    static let k1 =  UUID()
    static let k2 =  UUID()
    static let k3 =  UUID()
    static let k4 =  UUID()
    static let k5 =  UUID()
    static var castData: [Key : CastMember] = [
        k1 : CastMember( k1, "Silver, Rebecca", "Rebecca", "Silver"),
        k2 : CastMember( k2, "Sferza, Natalie", "Natalie", "Sferza"),
        k3 : CastMember( k3, "Bradley, Tucker", "Tucker", "Bradley"),
        k4 : CastMember( k4, "Bradley, Nicci", "Nicci", "Bradley"),
        k5 : CastMember( k5, "Cochran, Joanne", "Joanne", "Cochran")
    ]
}

@Observable final class Story {
    static var shared = Story()
    
    var cast: [CastMember.Key : CastMember] = CastData.castData
    var sortedCast: [CastMember] = []
    var modelIndex: [ModelIndex.Key : ModelIndex] = [:]
   
    init() {
        
        sortedCast = sortCast(on: .title, upDown: .up)
        let modelList: [ModelIndex] = cast.values.map({ ModelIndex($0) })
        modelList.forEach { modelIndex[$0.id] = $0 }
    }
}
extension Story {
    func sortCast( on: CastMember.SortOrder, upDown: CastMember.UpDown) -> [CastMember] {
        CastMember.sort(cast, on, upDown)
    }
}
extension Story {
    func title(selection: Key?) -> String {
        if let s = selection, let t = modelIndex[s]?.title { return t }
        return ""
    }
}
@Observable class CastMember: Model  {
    var id = Key()

    var title = ""
    var firstName = ""
    var lastName = ""
    
    init(_ id: Key, _ title: String, _ firstName: String, _ lastName: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.title = title
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.lastName = lastName
    }
}
extension CastMember {
    enum SortOrder {
        case title, last, first
    }
    
    enum UpDown {
        case up, down
    }
    
    static func sort (_ d: [CastMember.Key : CastMember], _ order: SortOrder, _ upDown : UpDown = .up) -> [CastMember]  {
        switch order {
        case .title: return d.values.sorted(by: { upDown == .up ? $0.title < $1.title : $0.title > $1.title })
        case .last: return d.values.sorted(by: { upDown == .up ? $0.lastName < $1.lastName : $0.lastName > $1.lastName })
        case .first: return d.values.sorted(by: { upDown == .up ? $0.firstName < $1.firstName : $0.firstName > $1.firstName })
        }
    }
}
```

[image: List with selection]

[image: List after sort showing sort menu]

How do I preserve the selection through the sort? Is List the appropriate way to implement this? The finished app will have several different sorts of lists and sort criteria. Also, some lists should allow drag & drop reordering.

Each list element has a persistent UUID identifier. Eventually, I will probably use SwiftData, but I wanted to work on the look and feel before tackling that learning curve. Or am I wasting time implementing functionality SwiftData would provide?

MacOS 14.2.1, Xcode 15.2

Comment: Fetch the selected string before, then sort, then select the string after.

Comment: Given the declarative design of Swiftui with its under-the-hood rendering algorithms, I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: What is `Key` type? I am trying to run your code but Xcode cannot find what it is.

Comment: Depending on what `Key` is, but you could try something 
 like this in your ContentView Menu Buttons, and wherever else you sort the stories.
 
 `let select1 = selection....
 story.sortedCast = story.sortCast(on: .dob, upDown: .up)
 if let select2 = story.sortedCast...first(where {$0.... == select1}) {
     selection... = select2
 }`

Comment: I would recommend to use `Story` object as `@StateObject` than `@State` in the root app.

Comment: Sorry. Left out a lot of boilerplate. Key is a type alias for UUID

Comment: What are the definitions of `ModelIndex`, `StoryDate`, and `CastData` then?

Comment: Storydate is a date container with extra stuff. There are several more types than CastMember. ModelIndex lets me find any type from its key

Comment: Cast data is json test data

Comment: Try to keep the selection stored in StateObject, I would say make Story as StateObject and keep the selection stored in it.

Comment: `Story` is a `@Observable final class` and so should use `@State`.
 It is not a `ObservableObject` where you would use `@StateObject`.
 See: [Apple info](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/migrating-from-the-observable-object-protocol-to-the-observable-macro) for specific examples of this.

Comment: When posting a code sample you should make sure it contains all the code needed to make it compile and try to removing things that aren't relevant to the issue (like decoding stuff for instance) so we can more easily understand it and use it to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Code should compile and run for you now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the array has been sorted the List gets redrawn as expected and this seems to happen in two different UI cycles because the `selection` property still has a value after the sort but for some reason `List` will reset it to nil.

So my workaround for this is to store the value of `selection` after the sort and then re-set it after a delay by doing it asynchronously.

This was done in an `.onChange` modifier

```
.onChange(of: story.sortedCast, initial: false) {
    if let currentSelection = selection {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            selection = currentSelection
        }
    }
}
```

Not an ideal solution but it seems to work as expected.

Comment: Placing this modifier after the menu modifer seems to work. I'm wondering how robust a solution this is, namely what undocumented implementation detail it depends on. Do you (or anyone reading this) understand why List clears the selection? And why it appears to render twice? Can you point me to a resource that delves under the hood of List rendering so I can understand this better.

Comment: SwiftUI is Apple’s own framework and not open source so we can’t really look under the hood but to me it looks like a bug in the List  implementation.

Comment: Me, too. Guess I'll see how robust the work-around is as I flesh out the app. Thanks